# Curved/Slanted Line CSS or SVG

Tags: html, css, svg

How exactly could I add something like [image: this] to my website? Using SVG, CSS or HTML. I am unable to find anything similar to this.

P.S Ignore the circle/ring please.

Comment: One simple way would be to create an image and add it as background image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least with SVG this is rather easy to achieve using a `<path>` and some [curve commands](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths#curve_commands):

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 30">
  <path d="M 0,0 100,0 100,30 Q 100,15 50,15 Q 0,15 0,0 Z" style="fill: steelblue;" />
</svg>
```